# How to restart self package after update

Tags: android, root, android-package-managers

I'm writing the MDM app, that can update itself via PM (`pm install -r my.apk`).
A several services in my app should be started after update. Can I do this? Devices are rooted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it is possible.

I had the same issue, i needed to update my app and restart it afterwards.
I solved it like this:

```
String command = "pm install -r " + filename + ";am start -n com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.Start";
```

This will install your app, and afterwards call "am start" to launch the app again. Just replace com.example.myapp with your package name, and the parameter after the / is the activity you want to launch.

I know this is an old post, but i came across it when i was searching for a solution, so maybe this can help others in the future :)

Comment: It works on one of my devices (Android 4.4, but doesn't work on the other - Android 5.1). I haven't found a way (yet) to make it work on both

Comment: Are both devices rooted?

Comment: I can confirm that this works on android 4.4 but not android 5.1 (both rooted devices)

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that self update is not possible. While self updating your app, system will kill process performing update.

You have two options:

- create second app that will execute `pm install -r my.apk` safely
- create simple update script in shell and make it run on device boot

Comment: @Dan i try to use your solution but sometime it works and sometime it unable to launch back main activity. Is there any other suitable way to do this as i dont want to make a separate application for this purpose. I have rooted device so may be there is a way to restart application main activity using command only.